# Time conversion milliseconds local time to milliseconds UTC time in android

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, utc

I have Current time in  **MILLISECONDS** of my device.

Now I need to convert it into  **MILLISECONDS OF UTC TIME-ZONE**

So I have tried this, but it is not converting in milliseconds.

```
public static long localToUTC(long time) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Log.e("* UTC : " + time, " - " + sdf.format(new Date(time)));
        Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date(time)));
        long timeInMilliseconds = date.getTime();
        Log.e("Millis in UTC", timeInMilliseconds + "" + new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(date));
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return time;
}
```

and vice-versa same for **UTC MILLISECOND** to **LOCAL TIME ZONE MILLISECOND**

Please, give me some advice.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you sure you're testing it correctly ? May be you can add sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it, it gives me right date, but when i take milliseconds from the date object long timeInMilliseconds = date.getTime(); it gives me some value which is not accurate, which i need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For LOCAL to UTC Millisecond and vice versa

**LOCAL TO UTC**

```
public static long localToUTC(long time) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date(time);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
//            System.out.println("Local Millis * " + date.getTime() + "  ---UTC time  " + strDate);//correct

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date utcDate = dateFormatLocal.parse(strDate);
//            System.out.println("UTC Millis * " + utcDate.getTime() + " ------  " + dateFormatLocal.format(utcDate));
            long utcMillis = utcDate.getTime();
            return utcMillis;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return time;
    }
```

and for **UTC TO LOCAL**

```
public static long utcToLocal(long utcTime) {
        try {
            Time timeFormat = new Time();
            timeFormat.set(utcTime + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(utcTime));
            return timeFormat.toMillis(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return utcTime;
    }
```

Thanks, I got this solution

Answer (score 1):

Some observations regarding your code:

- You set the formatter to UTC, so you interprete the time-parameter as UTC, not as "local milliseconds", as done in: `sdf.format(new Date(time)));`.
- `Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date(time)));` does not make any sense. You could just write without need to format and parse: `Date date = new Date(time);`

I don't know where you get the time-parameter from. But your statement that this is to be interpreted as "local milliseconds" seems to be based on a misunderstanding. When handling **globally valid instants/moments on UTC-timeline**, it is irrelevant where the instant time was measured (leaving clock failures aside). So the time-parameter might have been measured as device time via `System.currentTimeMillis()` etc. but you can directly compare it to any other instants (even on other devices) without any need for conversion.

If you really really have "local milliseconds" (should not be handled in public outside of a dedicated timezone library), then you need a timezone offset to handle the conversion, otherwise it is arbitrary guesswork. The formula for such a conversion would be in pseudo-code:

> [utc-time] = [local-time] minus [zone offset]

Comment: Thanks, i got solution making some mistake resolved.